# TF255273:Team Foundation Server is being configured by another process

Tags: tfs

While installing Team Foundation Server on Windows Server 2012, I am getting error message which is "Team Foundation Server is being configured by another process".

I have uninstalled TFS and try to install it again, but still getting the same message.

Please suggest.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot and run installer with admin rights.